# Collect TextInput in separate Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some Credit Card-related `TextInput`s in React Native. I want to collect these TextInputs in a separate Component.

So it looks something like

```
class CreditCard extends Component {
  state = { number: null, expirationMonth: null, expirationYear: null, cvc: null };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={...} ... />
        <TextInput onChangeText={...} ... />
        <TextInput onChangeText={...} ... />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and in my app, I am importing the Credit Card component and use it like

```
class AddCreditCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CreditCard ... />
        <Button disabled={creditCardIsInvalid} ... />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I know how to save data in state in the Credit Card component, but how can I extract the data from the Credit Card component to the container component (AddCreditCard)?

I guess it's something like adding a `creditCard` object to the container and an `onChange` property to `CreditCard`, so I can populate the creditCard object directly from the `CreditCard` component?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the state to the `AddCreditCard` component and pass a prop to the `CreditCard` component that will update the containers state.
That way you can access the data in `AddCreditCard` component via `state` and via `props` inside `CreditCard`

```
class AddCreditCard extends Component {

    state = { number: null, expirationMonth: null, expirationYear: null, cvc: null };

    textFieldChanged = (key, value) => {
        let newState = {};
        newState[key] = value;
        this.setState(newState);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <CreditCard 
                    textFieldChanged={this.textFieldChanged} 
                    number={this.state.number} 
                    expirationMonth={this.state.expirationMonth} 
                    expirationYear={this.state.expirationYear} 
                    cvc={this.state.cvc} 
                />
                <Button disabled={creditCardIsInvalid} ... />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
class CreditCard extends Component {
    render() {
        // this.props.number ...
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput 
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.props.textFieldChanged('number', text)
                    }}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.props.textFieldChanged('expirationMonth', text)
                    }}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.props.textFieldChanged('expirationYear', text)
                    }}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.props.textFieldChanged('cvc', text)
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I then be able to define `creditCardIsInvalid`? Would I have to do it in all containers with `<CreditCard />`? Also, I need to pass initial data from `AddCreditCard` to `CreditCard` - so would I have to use `state = { number: this.props.number, ... }` in `CreditCard`?

Comment: Yes and Yes! :)